# Styled Components: nesting and referring to other components at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

```
<FooterLight transparent={true}/>
```

Is it possible to have a nested rule in definition of FooterLight for which the props value transparent is evaluated. Then it assigns 'color: white' to its children ChangelogVersion and CopyRight?

Next two questions:

1. Since color: white !important is the same for ChangelogVersion and CopyRight. Can these be merged together in one statement?
2. Does &&& work to not use !important?

---

```
export const FooterLight = styled(Navbar).attrs({fixed: 'bottom'})`
  background-color: ${props => props.transparent
  ? 'transparent'
  : 'white'};

  ${props => props.transparent && ChangelogVersion} {
    color: white !important;
  }

  ${props => props.transparent && CopyRight} {
    color: white !important;
  }
`


export const ChangelogVersion = styled(NavLink)`
  &&& {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    padding-right: .5rem;
  }
`

export const CopyRight = styled.div `
  padding: .5rem 0;
  color: '#777777';
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure can... You could do something like this:

```
export const FooterLight = styled(Navbar).attrs({fixed: 'bottom'})`
    background-color: ${props => props.transparent
    ? 'transparent'
    : 'white'};

    ${ChangelogVersion}, ${CopyRight} {
         ${props => props.transparent && "color: white !important;"}
    }
`
```

As for your second statement, `&&&` might work but you're better off structuring the CSS better so it doesn't need to be `!important` in the first place... In you're example there's no reason for any of the `important`s to be there, so it's hard to offer a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. Works as requested. I just had to re order the elements to feature ChangelogVersion and CopyRight before FooterLight.

One more Question: can you also edit the attrs of ChangelogVersion through the prop element of FooterLight?